# redirect to stripe checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments

i have my website in ruby on rails 5 and i'm updating my stripe payment gateway with [this link](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/set-up-a-subscription#create-checkout-session) but clicking my button doesn't redirect me to the stripe checkout, this is what i have in the controller:

```
def index

    Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]

    session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [{
        price: 'price_1HKywnBS16ZK5Vr3GYCRvTir',
        quantity: 1,
      }],
      mode: 'subscription',
      success_url: 'https://www.my_site.network/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
      cancel_url: 'https://www.my_site.network/cancel',
    )

end
```

I think the error may be when replacing the session id in the javascript code of my index view:

```
<button id="checkout-button">Pay</button>

<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var stripe = Stripe('<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>');

    var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button');


    checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        // Make the id field from the Checkout Session creation API response
        // available to this file, so you can provide it as argument here
        // instead of the {{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}} placeholder.
        sessionId: '<%=session.id%>'
      }).then(function (result) {
        // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
        // error, display the localized error message to your customer
        // using `result.error.message`.
      });
    });




</script>
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, if you could it would be helpful to see what (if any) errors show in the browser console when you click the Checkout button. That should shed more light on the issue: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open

Comment: @ttmarek you are right, the console give me this error (index):1 Uncaught IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: Invalid value for sessionId. You specified '340b63dc228dcafdd225f23ee789b573'.

Comment: @ttmarek I think I'm not showing the id of the session, how can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't have to use **'<%=session.id%>'**.
The value that you must to use there is the entire value that you store in **session** when you do: **Stripe::Checkout::Session.create** in your controller.